# issue while using union clause with order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

While placing the union in between two statements it is giving out some error. Code is given below:

I tried placing the brackets starting at select statement and ending at order by name. But, nothing works for me. Can someone please suggest what is wrong with this code?

```
select TOP(1) name from hack
where len(name) in (select max(len(name)) from hack )
order by name

UNION

select TOP(1) name from hack
where len(name) in (select min(len(name)) from hack )
order by name
```

Receving the error mentioned below:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? I suppose you need subqueries to involve ORDER BY.

Comment: Yes I am using SQL Server. Adding subquery works for me. Thanks :)

Comment: if you remove the fist order by name right before Union; you will not get any more error and your query will give the expected result set you need. Please read up about "query execution order" (hint why you can use column alias in order by clause).

Answer (score 1):

The `where` is not necessary:

```
select h.*
from (select top (1) name
       from hack h
       order by len(name), name asc
     ) h
union all
select h.*
from (select top (1) name
       from hack h
       order by len(name) desc, name
     ) h;
```

Comment: I tried this query. But what If there are two names having same length. One is starting with 'a' and another with 'm'. So in that case query must show the name starting with 'a' but after executing this query it is showing name with 'm'. Can you please let me know how I can I modify this query for better results?

Comment: @user11497433 . . . Just add a second key to the `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use subqueries:

```
select name
from   (
         select TOP(1) name 
         from hack 
         where len(name) in (select max(len(name)) from hack )
         order by name
      ) A

UNION

select name
from   (
         select TOP(1) name 
         from hack 
         where len(name) in (select min(len(name)) from hack )
         order by name
      ) B
```

Comment: Thanks HoneyBadger. This is really helpful. Just wanted to know that what makes you to nest one more query.

Answer (score 0):

Access table only once:

```
SELECT a.Name
FROM (
    SELECT h.Name
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY LEN(h.Name) DESC, h.Name) AS [rnMax]
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY LEN(h.Name) ASC, h.Name) AS [rnMin]
    FROM hack h
) a
WHERE (a.rnMin = 1 OR a.rnMax = 1)
GROUP BY a.Name
ORDER BY a.Name
;
```